# Calendar DAY_OF_WEEK returns wrong day - always Saturday

Tags: java, android, dayofweek

I'm a beginner in programming and this is my first question to my android project in java.

I'd like to create a Spinner with 7 items. These items shall display the last seven days.
Well - today is Tuesday, the entries should be like this:

today - Monday - Sunday - Saturday - .... - Wednesday

My calculation is right and the days are listed downward. 
But when I log the 'DAY_OF_WEEK' the result is always 7 (Saturday) and I have no idea why.

That's why my items are listed as
-today- -Friday- -Thusday- ...
everyday!

TimeZone/PhoneDate/PhoneTime ... everything seems okay

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
// CalendarState for DayOfWeek: Sunday 1, Monday 2, ... Saturday 7
int currentDay = calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
logger.severe("CURRENT DAY OF WEEK: " + currentDay);
```

Maybe you notice my mistake? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You want to call `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`.

Comment: It's that easy? Never expected - Thank you!!

Answer (score 6):

`DAY_OF_WEEK` is an enumerator value, and therefore constant.

You need to use `get(DAY_OF_WEEK);` on the `calendar` reference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

for more details . See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) on developers.android page.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!